# Need to make a div opacity property progressively higher on each mouseover in JS

Tags: javascript, css, event-handling, opacity

Noob here.

I am making an etch a sketch project and I have hit a stumbling block.  Everything works except I am having trouble getting the squares to go darker when i revisit them with the mouse.  The aim is for the opacity to become darker by 10% on each visit of the square.  I have compiled the code in code pen:

https://codepen.io/dwdy250/pen/BxZYEE

The function which deals with adding the event listeners and updating the squares is as follows:

```
function addListeners(){  //adds event listener and function that colors squares

    squares.forEach((squares) => {

        squares.addEventListener('mouseover', () =>{

            squares.setAttribute("style","background-color:black; display:inline-block;");
              squares.style.height = squareSize;
            squares.style.width = squareSize;
            squares.style.opacity += 0.1;

        });
    });
}
```

I have looked into others work on the same project and they seem to have used the this.style.opacity = Number(this.style.opacity) + 0.1;  however when I use this is just get 'this.style is undefined'...  I guess I don't really understand how or why to use 'this' yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting the style on div in every mouse over event

`squares.setAttribute("style","background-color:black; display:inline-block;");`

Try to remove this line of code and work it in different way

Answer (score 0):

What about using backgroundColor?
You can decrement the r, g and b value to go from grey to black

```
var r = 64;
var g = 64;
var b = 64;

function addListeners(){  //adds event listener and function that colors squares

    squares.forEach((squares) => {

        squares.addEventListener('mouseover', () =>{

            squares.setAttribute("style","display:inline-block;");


      squares.style.height = squareSize;
      squares.style.width = squareSize;
      squares.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
      r -= 4;
      g -= 4;
      b -= 4;
    });
});
```

}